# ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application - paramiko

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, 64-bit, paramiko

I have a situation in win7 64bit, after I installing paramiko 1.12.1 by using easy_install paramiko,I'm using 64bit python2.7 , also installed 64bit pycrypto, there is a import error：

```
   >>> import paramiko
    enter code hereenter code hereTraceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
        import paramiko
      File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\paramiko\__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
      File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\paramiko\transport.py", line 33, in <module>
      File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\paramiko\util.py", line 33, in <module>
      File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\paramiko\common.py", line 98, in <module>
      File "c:\users\yapan\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-6upp3i\pycrypto-2.6-py2.7-win-amd64.egg.tmp\Crypto\Random\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
      File "c:\users\yapan\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-6upp3i\pycrypto-2.6-py2.7-win-amd64.egg.tmp\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
      File "c:\users\yapan\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-6upp3i\pycrypto-2.6-py2.7-win-amd64.egg.tmp\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py", line 28, in <module>
      File "c:\users\yapan\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-6upp3i\pycrypto-2.6-py2.7-win-amd64.egg.tmp\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\winrandom.py", line 7, in <module>
      File "c:\users\yapan\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-6upp3i\pycrypto-2.6-py2.7-win-amd64.egg.tmp\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\winrandom.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
    ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Any thoughs?

Answer (score 5):

This is a problem I ran into as well.  I have Windows Server 2012 64 bit and python 32 bit.  What I ended up doing is letting pip solve everything.
I have pip 1.6.dev1.

1. pip install --upgrade paramiko

   *if you get this error during upgrade:

   > AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'rollback', do:

   1. pip uninstall pycrypto and enter (y)
   2. pip install pycrypto
   3. pip install ecdsa

Basically, just try to run that first command, and follow the tracebacks to resolve whatever dependency is missing.  This worked for me.

I saved my session in txt if you need it for reference.

-Daniel

Answer (score 1):

If you are having trouble building and installing Python 2.7 components that depend on compiled C modules, I highly recommend you check out Microsoft's specially packaged compiler for Python 2.7, here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44266

I had ALL kinds of trouble getting pycrypto to install on Windows 7 64-bit (I was trying to get Fabric to work, which depends on paramiko which depends on pycrypto).  After installing the aforementioned compiler and then doing:

```
pip install wheel
pip uninstall pycrypto paramiko
pip install paramiko
```

Everything just started working!  Hope that helps anyone landing on this answer from Google in the future.